# Is there a configuration utility for an Intel embedded graphics card?

Tags: graphics, configuration, intel

I would like to change some settings of my Intel G41 embedded graphics card using an application, like I can do in windows or with Nvidia or AMD in Linux. Is there something like that for Intel in Ubuntu-Linux?

Comment: Can you please add which settings you want to change? Maybe somebody knows how you can do that without a special configuration utility.

Comment: Same problem where, I would like to change some settings like Antialising, VSync etc... in order to boost my system when using 3D .... I can only do that with Catalyst and Nvidia Settings... Are the settings directly in the driver or in the Xorg configuration files ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)